# How can I use the Twitter API to look up accounts from email addresses?

Tags: python, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm helping out a newly formed startup build a social media following, and I have a csv file of thousands of email addresses of people I need to follow. From looking at the twitter API, I see its possible to follow the accounts if I knew their usernames, but its unclear how to look them up by email. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be an option with their API, you can use either user_id or screen name with their GET users/show or GET users/lookup options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a lookup based on email address in the Twitter API.